# What is the best method of detecting a collision between these two objects in opencv (python)?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, collision-detection, collision

I am required to prevent an extruder from touching the base of a stage. I chose to use opencv on python to detect collision between the two objects. After researching past posts and reading up on opencv's processing tools I decided to try a few methods. The first method was edge detection which proved to be lacking in position detection. Next I tried using color as an advantage to isolate the needle and the stage, place rectangles surrounding the objects, and then prevent the rectangles from touching. This is proving to be a challenge because the background and needle are pretty much the same color. The last method requires using box-box collision but my guess is that if I am having issues with the second method then this method will also prove difficult. I am thinking about trying out deep learning on opencv, taking a bunch of photos, and the training the program but I am not sure how that would play out since ill be getting feed from video. Can anyone give me any tips? Any algorithms that would be helpful here? I see that the needle is clearly defined due to its edges so how can I use that to my advantage here? Any help is appreciated.

Photo of needle and stage:

[image]

Comment: Try edge detection (canny filter) then find the contours, finding the location of each object. Once you know the location and dimensions of the objects, there are many ways of finding if they have collided.

Comment: There are object tracking algorithms in cv2 that could be useful. I am guessing that in your video feed the background remains the same, but the needle moves? If so the tracking might allow you to drag a box across the needle.
As for how usefull it is depends a bit on how you envision your program running. Do you want it to run completly autonomous or can you give some input at start and let it run?

Comment: @ZWang The problem with finding the edges and contouring is that I get back a lot of contours. I usually have to find the one I need using a trackbar but the final program should not be needing to find the contour. But let's say I do find the right contour and can do it without using a trackbar, how will i find the location using the contour?

Comment: @AlexS Actually, the stage moves, the background is the same, and the needle is stationary. The program can have a bit of input in the beginning but really it should be understandable to anyone that doesnt know computer vision or programming even. Now since the stage moves then I should be able to use tracking you say?

Comment: @MyProgramSucks If the objects don't change in dimensions, you can filter out the contours that are useless and only keep the ones of the objects. OpenCV has built in function of finding the centroid of the contour. https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html

Comment: @ZWang Wouldnt the contour area be a better feature than the centroid if I want to find my contour? I can see that the centroid could be calculated for all the contours and the one closest to the centroid of the actual needle would be the contour I want to keep but wouldnt the area require less calculation/